# How to create simple websocket chat application in PHP using Apache server without javascript

Tags: php, websocket

Now I'm working in websocket in php platform. Initially I start this websocket, a lot of people discussed this topic but the proper guidance with source is only available in javascript websocket not php.

And I'm surfing many tutorialspoint and youtubes, thir works have some of mistakes. Finally I fix the issues and implement websocket without help of javascript. And I'd like to share my works with you.

I hope this is help to create websocket in php without javascript (For Beginners).

> NOTE: Before proceeding this code, check if `socket` is enabled to your `php.ini` file. This is help to create socket in php

I add my works is one of the answer of this post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Server.php

```php
<?php

    $host = "127.0.0.1";
    $port = "20205";
    set_time_limit(0);

    $sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
    $result = socket_bind($sock, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");

    $result = socket_listen($sock, 3) or die("Could not setup socket listener\n");

    class Chat {
        function readline() {
            return rtrim(fgets(STDIN));
        }
    }

    do {
        $accept = socket_accept($sock) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");
        $msg    = socket_read($accept, 1024) or die("Could not read input\n");

        $msg    = trim($msg);
        echo "Client Says:\t".$msg."\n\n";

        $line = new Chat();
        echo "Enter reply:\t";
        $reply=$line->readline();

        socket_write($accept, $reply, strlen($reply)) or die("Could not write output\n");
    }while(true);

    socket_close($accept, $sock);

?>
```

> Client.php

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div align="center"></div>

    <form method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Enter Message</label>
                    <input type="text" name="txtMessage">
                    <input type="submit" name="btnSend" value="Send">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
                $host = "127.0.0.1";
                $port = "20205";

                if (isset($_POST['btnSend'])) {
                    $msg = $_REQUEST['txtMessage'];
                    $sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
                    socket_connect($sock, $host, $port);

                    socket_write($sock, $msg, strlen($msg));

                    $reply = socket_read($sock, 1924);
                    $reply = trim($reply);

                    $reply = "Server says:\t".$reply;
                }
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <textarea rows="10" cols="30"><?php echo @$reply; ?></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

> How to run Application

1. Run `server.php` file via command prompt using this below line

```
php Server.php
```

2. Run `client.php` file via browser
3. In browser (client) - Send message
4. In command prompt  (server) - It display the client message and ask the reply for us.
5. In command prompt  (server) - You send reply.
6. In browser (client) - the message will be displayed.

Comment: This is not "using Apache"...

Comment: Hello, thank you for simplifying the problem. However your question is "How to create simple websocket chat application in PHP using Apache server without javascript" but the solution you provide is for PHP client.